# javax.xml.crypto custom CanonicalizationMethod for old specefications

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-dsig

I'm trying to validate xml signed with

```
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991115"/>
```

But I get an exception:

`javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991115 for provider XMLDSig`

I don't like option to change xml input. Looks like implementing of some custom canonicalization method or force java to use other is much better, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
final NodeList signatureNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(SIGNATURE_TAG_NAME);
  if (signatureNodeList.getLength() == 0)
    return false;
  for(int i = 0; i < signatureNodeList.getLength(); i++){
    final DOMValidateContext validateContext = new DOMValidateContext(
      new KeyValueKeySelector(), signatureNodeList.item(i));
    final XMLSignature signature = xmlSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(
      validateContext);
    if(!signature.validate(validateContext))
      return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the [`CanonicalizationMethod` values defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/CanonicalizationMethod.html#field.summary) in JDK 8:

- http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
- http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments

Specifically, the 1999 working draft that you're using (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991115) isn't among them.

> I don't like option to change xml input.

From the [implementation of `XMLDSigRI`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.xml.crypto/com.springsource.javax.xml.crypto/1.4.3/org/jcp/xml/dsig/internal/dom/XMLDSigRI.java) you can probably work out how to create a new provider that implements that specific version.

However, I'd seriously consider whether it's valuable to have an implementation of an obsolete draft, especially when cryptography is involved.